# Angular html loop doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to write a loop for an array and it doesn't work. Rather than do this for HTML:

```
  {{organization.minutesToNext[0].ID}}
  {{organization.minutesToNext[0].time}}
  {{organization.minutesToNext[1].ID}}
  {{organization.minutesToNext[1].time}}
```

I'd rather a loop like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="minutesToNext in organization"> 

   next stop {{minutesToNext.ID}} in {{minutesToNext.time}}  sec
</li>
```

But this doesn't work. Please help me find my error

Comment: What does `organization` contain?, as far as i see in the controller you only have `busList` in your contoller, that's the only scope you can bind to the view...

Comment: Would you please instead of `angular.forEach($scope.busList,function(value,index){...})` do `console.log(busList)` and add it the description?

Comment: Add `bus.json` content to the description please.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML should look like that :

```
   <li ng-repeat="orga in organization.minutesToNext"> 
         next {{orga.ID}} in {{orga.time}} sec
             </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

What i can see is that you dont have a `$scope.organization` to bind to the view, so i'll guess `$scope.busList` contains the info.

Your controller will be like this:

```
.controller('busCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("bus.json")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.busList = response.get_cars;
        }
```

You'll bind `$scope.busList`, that's in the controller, to the view:

```
<li ng-repeat="minutesToNext in busList.organization.minutesToNext">
    next {{minutesToNext.ID}} in {{minutesToNext.time}} sec
</li>
```